# Compiling mod-wsgi - How to install python3-devel on centos-6.8

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, django, mod-wsgi, repository

I'm trying to deploy Django-1.10 on Centos-6.8 using default apache in centos(version 2.2).
I'm using python 3.4.5.I'm not able to compile mod-wsgi without python3-devel. Centos-6.8 repos doesn't have python3-devel packages by default.
I need help in compiling mod-wsgi for python-3.4.5 in centos-6.8.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was [shamelessly copied from stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642937/deploy-a-python3-4-based-django-project-on-centos-6-5-with-mod-wsgi-doable) and then modified by replacing python & wsgi versions for newer ones without any testing. It was tested to work on clean CentOS 6.8. So if it doesn't work for you, then you probably doing something wrong...

First, install EPEL...

```
yum -y -q install http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

Then Apache...

```
yum -y -q install httpd mod_ssl httpd-devel
```

Then for Python (including some very commonly used pre-reqs):

```
yum -y -q groupinstall development
yum -y -q install zlib2-devel openssl-devel sqlite-devel bzip2-devel python-devel openssl-devel openssl-perl libjpeg-turbo libjpeg-turbo-devel zlib-devel giflib ncurses-devel gdbm-devel xz-devel tkinter readline-devel tk tk-devel kernel-headers glibc libpng gcc-c++ wget
```

Install Python 3.6.0:

```
wget 'http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tgz'
tar -xzf 'Python-3.6.0.tgz'
cd ./Python-3.6.0
CXX=g++ ./configure --prefix=/usr --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --datadir=/usr/share --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var/lib --libdir=/usr/lib64 --with-fpectl --enable-shared --enable-ipv6 --with-threads --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --with-computed-gotos --with-dbmliborder=gdbm --with-libc= --with-system-expat --with-system-ffi 
make
make install
echo "/usr/lib/python3.6" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python36.conf
echo "/usr/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python36.conf
```

Make and compile mod_wsgi (or look into MOD WSGI Express!):

```
wget "https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.5.14.tar.gz"
tar -xzf '4.5.14.tar.gz'
cd ./mod_wsgi-4.5.14
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.6
make
make install
```

Comment: entering the ./configure --with... , I get the python.h not found error.  I have installed all the dev-packages, stuck here

Comment: You should try https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tgz nowadays

Comment: I would like to ask the question: apache2 - python3.6 - mod_wsgi, do you have a clear tutorial on how to achieve running the wsgi with only python 3.x?  I am really lost in all the info and possible solutions that don't work

Comment: @hewi. Can you tell (confirm) me your OS version (CentOS 6.8) and mod_wsgi version your need. Does Apache 2.2 - Python 3.6 - mod_wsgi 4.5.14 work for you?

Comment: @hewi I've tested my solution to work with clean CentOS 6.8 distro.

Comment: I am on Kubuntu

Comment: @hewi Kubuntu can't be considered business environment, but i'm sure if you replace yum with apt, those commands will do just what they do on CentOS

Comment: I almost got it working, I am just struggling to point the sys.path to the python35 folder

Comment: @hewi So I guess you had compiled it successfully after all. If you'd like a help with your sys.path problems please open a separate question. [This guide may also help](http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/)

Comment: no, I used sudo pat-get install apache2-mod-wsgi-py3; this should not be the reason why the actual wsgi script cannot find python3.5, it must have to do with sys.path

Comment: @hewi this is completely unrelated to the topic. I don't know thy you want to post that here....